How to hide other repositories in GitHub Desktop when switching to other account
I am confused by how logging out and logging into a new/fresh account in Github Desktop works. I made a new one for scripts that are only for my institution, not my private account. I signed out and then signed into the new one. First it said something about "This commit will be misattributed" so I clicked on update email and then it looked normal.
Then I still saw the old projects from my personal account, which are in the Documents\Github directory on my local PC and that's why it started showing them as downloadable, I guess? I do not want that. I want to go clean slate and only see repositories I am going to create on this fresh account from now on. Am I even logged out of my old account? This is way more confusing than I thought it would be.

I'm not sure it will help you, but as for making sure you're completely logged out of GitHub, there are 3 things to do: 1) go to github.com and clear all the cookies for that site 2) open the ".gitconfig" file at C:\Users[your-account-name] with Notepad and replace the entries "name" and "email" with an "x" 3) go to Windows Control Panel, click on "User Accounts", then click on "Manage Your Credentials", then click on "Windows Credentials", then select each credential below and click "Remove"

You need to explain what repositories you have. They should be separate too (your work repos should not have your personal projects in it, and vice versa). I would think however that you can use any repo you have access to in any account ... so if you see personal repos when logged in with your "institutional" account, it probably just means that your "institutional account" also has access to your personal repos. However, I'm really shooting from the hip here ... maybe that github desktop even lets you be logged in to two accounts at the same time ... anything is possible.
